# the usage of "insalubrious"

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

Does it make sense to say an insalubrious relationship between two countries?
If not, what would be a better replacement?

hey this is my first post on this website..
I'm a non-native english speaker..
THANKS a lot!

Comment: how about *unhealthy*?

Answer (score 2):

Insalubrious is primarily used to mean *unhealthy/not conducive to health*. Though *unhealthy* can be used to describe relations between two countries, I wouldn't use *insalubrious* itself.

Example of Insalubrious from the [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insalubrious):

> *After inhaling the **insalubrious** city smog for a month, I was happy to once again breathe in the fresh air of the country*

To describe relations between countries, you can simply use unhealthy, or "***strained***", or perhaps "***hostile***" if you're looking for a far stronger word.

Per the [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/strained):

> **strained**: *adjective*
>
> If a relationship is strained, problems are spoiling that
>   relationship:
>
> *Relations between the two countries have become strained (= difficult) recently.*